# COnditional Format for cells in a colomn based on value of corresponding Row in another Colomn

Tags: excel-formula

keep messing up formula trying to do a conditional format for cells in a column based on if the corresponding Row in another Column has a specific Value.

="IF+$A:$Arow() = D ?
Don't think I'm even close but I need the condition format For all of Column H to check the same Row in column A If its a D then format the cell.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try this as the formula for your conditional formatting: `=$A$2=7` or this if checking for a string: `=EXACT($A$2,"Test")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all cells in column H, say H1 has a column header, so you select H2 to H100, click Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine ...

Enter this formula:

=$A2="D"

Select a format and confirm all dialogs.

When you select all cells from H2 down, the cell H2 will be the active cell. The conditional formatting formula contains a cell address in column A with a relative row reference, i.e. there is no $ sign in front of the row number. The most important bit is that this row number must be the same row number as the active cell when you create the conditional format, so if your selection starts in a different row, you need to adjust the formula accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Thank You Teylyn, That does work but the worksheet will continuously have more Rows added by multiple sources. There is no way to apply it to the entire column?

Comment: OKay this works with selecting all of H as a column but Had to use A1 even without the D in it still applied to all below. Thank you much in the end it was super simple formula.

Comment: Adding CF to a whole column is not a very good idea, since it may lead to spreadsheet slowness. Consider using a Excel table for your data (Insert ribbon > Table), which will apply formatting and formulas to new and inserted rows automatically, without the overhead of formatting a million rows.